# R Plotly Disable Legend Click and Legend Double Click

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I would like to disable the plotly legend selection from the server side using the R Plotly. We see [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/disable-legend-click-functionality-hiding-traces/1345/2) that it is possible to achieve this on plotly javascript using the following,

`gd.on('plotly_legendclick',function() { return false; })`

Is there any way we can achieve this in R using `event_register()` or `event_data()`?

I found a hacky solution using CSS to disable the legend. However, if you have multiple different plots for the same `output$gg`, the CSS code disables the legend for all plots.

Reprex:

The final goal, clicking on the legend below must not hide any of the points.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("gg"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("doubleclick")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$gg <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point() + 
      facet_wrap(~vs)
    ggplotly(p) %>%
      event_register("plotly_legendclick") %>%
      event_register("plotly_legenddoubleclick")
  })

  output$click <- renderPrint({
    event_data("plotly_legendclick")
  })

  output$doubleclick <- renderPrint({
    event_data("plotly_legenddoubleclick")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `htmlwidgets::onRender`:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
w <- gl(3,5)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, w = w)
example <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = w)) + geom_line()

ggplotly(example) %>% 
  onRender("function(el,x){el.on('plotly_legendclick', function(){ return false; })}")
```

Answer (score 2):

`htmlwidgets::onRender` isn't needed. We can simply use `layout()`:

```
library(plotly)

x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
w <- gl(3, 5)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, w = w)
example <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = w)) + geom_line()

ggplotly(example) %>% layout(legend = list(
  itemclick = FALSE,
  itemdoubleclick = FALSE,
  groupclick = FALSE
))
```

Run `schema()`and navigate:

> object ► layout ► layoutAttributes ► legend ► itemclick

for more information on these parameters.